# RecyclerView: viewHolder.adapterPosition returns wrong value

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView to display a list of items user has created. I store names and IDs of items in arrayList using sharedPreferences. I want user to be able to delete items by swiping them, but viewHolder.adapterPosition returns wrong values, as well as viewHolder.layoutPosition, and I don`t know what to do with it, although I have another RecyclerView and there it works perfectly fine.

```
abstract class SwipeSchedule(context: Context) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

    private val deleteColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.delete_color)
    private val deleteIcon = R.drawable.ic_delete_24

    override fun getMovementFlags(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Int {
        // Check here whatever you want, return 0 if you want disable swipe.
        if (viewHolder.adapterPosition == -1) return 0

        return super.getMovementFlags(recyclerView, viewHolder)
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {
        RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
            .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(deleteColor)
            .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(deleteIcon)
            .create()
            .decorate()
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
    }

}
```

In MainActivity:

```
        val swipeSchedule = object : SwipeSchedule(this
        ) {
            @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                runBlocking {
                    //deleteAnim(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    Handler().postDelayed({
                        toast(viewHolder.layoutPosition.toString())
                        //schedulesList.remove(SchedulesRVModal(schedulesList[viewHolder.adapterPosition].scheduleName, schedulesList[viewHolder.adapterPosition].scheduleId))
                    }, 200)
                }
            }
        }
        val touchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeSchedule)
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.selectDeviceList)
```

And this is how I add new items:

```
        binding.addSchedule.setOnClickListener {
            var schName = "0"
            var schId = 0
            //lateinit var schList: ArrayList<SchedulesRVModal>

            if(schedulesList.isNotEmpty()) {
                schName = schedulesList[schedulesList.lastIndex].scheduleName
                schId = schedulesList[schedulesList.lastIndex].scheduleId + 1
            }
            schedulesList.add(SchedulesRVModal(schName, schId))
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

            val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
            val gson = Gson()
            val json: String = gson.toJson(schedulesList)
            editor.putString("schedules", json)
            editor.apply()
        }
```

The link leads to the video which shows what exactly wrong with adapterPosition I get.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eePDN9UAPWiAPduEV5JevgYrCISIO3t-/view?usp=sharing

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()) documentation which states "Note that if you've called RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), until the next layout pass, the return value of this method will be RecyclerView.NO_POSITION. " RecyclerView.NO_POSITION == -1. Take another look at the problem you are having and maybe update your question.

Comment: @Cheticamp, thank you, now I call notifyDataSetChanged() after a small delay and now it works fine!